# What are the effects of doing an autopsy?

Tags: startopia

An effect I notice from doing an autopsy in Startopia (placing a dead body in the Analyser) is the report that is shown after the analysis is complete. Does the report have any significance? (Not sure if it's part of the game humor or has actual gameplay information.)

Besides that, are there any other effects of doing an autopsy (better technology or other effect in the station or its denizens)?

[image: An autopsy being done in Startopia]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the postmortem report is really all you get from this, it's just an interesting little quirk/trick that's available to you.

The contents of the report *are* relevant - it should actually detail what they died from, which of their stats were particularly low, etc - so I guess if you've got dead peeps turning up and you don't know *why* it might be handy, but otherwise the reports are unlikely to have much impact on your game.